# How to post AJAX response to all logged in users as an update

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I currently have this code that post for only one user and i want to know if it's possible, that the ajax response can be posted as an update to all logged in users as an update on the website. I appreciate all efforts.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="postForm">
<input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['USERID']; ?>" />
    <select name="type" class="form-control" style="border:1px solid #eee; border-radius:5px; width:auto !important;">
    <option value="">select type of post</option>
    <option value="default">Normal Post</option>
    <option value="Testimonies">Testimonies</option>
    <option value="Prayer">Prayer Request</option>
    <option value="counselling">Counselling</option>
    <option value="Dreams">Dreams Interpretation</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="form-control" style="border:none; resize:none;" rows="1" name="post" id="post" placeholder="What's God saying through you today? <?php $text = explode(' ', $_SESSION['NAME']); echo $text[0]; ?>"></textarea>

      <button type="submit" value="postForm" class="submitIt btn btn-info btn-flat">Post</button>

  </form>
```

The AJAX Part

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){                         
 $( "body" ).delegate( ".submitIt", "click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 e.stopPropagation(); 
 //the button value 
 $url = "http://localhost/christ/ajaxPages/";
 var buttonValue = $(this).val();
 //alert(buttonValue);
 if(buttonValue == "postForm") {
 var formdata = $('#postForm').serialize();
 //alert(formdata);
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: $url + "addit.php",
  data: formdata,
  success: function(data){
  $("#discuss").append(data);
  $("#post").each(function(){autosize.destroy(this);});
  $("#post").val("");
   }
    })
       });
 </script>
```

This is the addit.php file called by above ajax

```
<?php
 include '.././config.php';
     //waste in dispose
     $arr[] =0;
 $db_con = connect();
$sect =  $_POST['post'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//time of psoidting
$time = strtotime($date);
 $sql = "insert into post(post_body,userId,post_type,date) values(:data,:userId,:type,:dateposted)";
$bio = $db_con->prepare($sql);
$bio->bindParam('data', $sect);
$bio->bindParam('type', $type);
$bio->bindParam('userId', $userId);
$bio->bindParam('dateposted', $date);
$bio->execute();
  $arr = $bio->errorInfo();
   if($arr[2] == "") {
    $disc =  $db_con->prepare("select * from post where post_body = :text and userId = :userId");
         $disc->bindParam("text", $sect);
         $disc->bindParam('userId', $userId);
         $disc->execute();
         $row = $disc->fetch();
         $_SESSION['postId'] = $row['post_id'];
   //let us retrive 
echo '<!-- Box Comment -->
      <div class="box box-widget" id="lofty-'.$row['post_id'].'">
      <div class="box-header with-border" style="border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;">
          <div class="user-block">
            <img class="img-circle" src="'.$url.'/'.userName('icon', $_SESSION['USERID']).'" alt="User Image">
            <span class="username"><a style="color:#1da1f2;" href="#">'.ucfirst($_SESSION['NAME']).'</a></span>
           <span class="description">Shared - ';
           echo humanTiming($time);
           echo '</span>
          </div>
           <!-- /.user-block -->
          <div class="box-tools">';
           if($row['userId'] == $_SESSION['USERID']) { 
          echo '<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span style="color:#fff">Dropdown Example</span>
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
  <li><a href="#"><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" class="btn btn-box-tool edit" id="edit-post-'.$row['post_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</button></li>
  <li><a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool submitIt" value="delete" name="del-'.$row['post_id'].'-'.$_SESSION['USERID'].'-post"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</button></a></li>
</ul>
</div>'; 
 }
          echo '</div>
          <!-- /.box-tools -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <p style="white-space:pre-wrap";><span id="replace-'.$row['post_id'].'">'.$sect.'</span></p>
          <div style="margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-10px; padding:4px 4px 0 4px;">
          <div class="col-lg-6" style="text-align:left">
          <span class="text-muted">       
    <button style="background:none; border:none;" class="btn btn-box-tool BigLike" name="like-'.$row['post_id'].'-'.$_SESSION['USERID'].'">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> <span id="change'.$row['post_id'].'"></span></button>
          <span id="seeIt'.$row['post_id'].'"></span><span id="seeItbefore'.$row['post_id'].'"></span></span>
          </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6" style="text-align:right">
           <span class="text-muted">
          <span id="seeIt2'.$row['post_id'].'"></span><span id="seeItbefore2'.$row['post_id'].'"></span>
           </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
        <div class="box-footer box-comments" style="background:none; margin:0;" id="comment'.$row['post_id'].'"></div>
        <!-- /.box-footer -->
        <div class="box-footer" style="border:none; padding-top:1px;">
          <form action="." method="post">
          <img class="img-responsive img-circle img-sm" src="'.$url.'/'.userName('icon', $_SESSION['USERID']).'" alt="user image">
            <!-- .img-push is used to add margin to elements next to floating images -->
            <div class="img-push">
            <textarea type="text" style="border-radius:20px; background:#eee; border:none; resize:none; overflow:hidden" rows="1" class="form-control input-sm comment-'.$_SESSION['USERID'].'" name="comment-'.'3-'.$row['post_id'].'-'.$_SESSION['USERID'].'"  placeholder="Press enter to post comment"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-widget -->         
         <!-- /.box -->';
    } else  {
      echo 'Failed';    
      } 
   ?>
```

I want to know if it's possible to modify this code to post the ajax response to all logged in users on the website rather than just the user that made the post. Forgive my English

Comment: The phrase "_as an update on the website_" doesn't really have any meaning to us unless we know exactly what it is you are "updating", and how that should effect the users.

Comment: You will need to implement pooling a web service and integrate this on all pages, pool the webservice and work with the response, or use a push service

Comment: When user make post on the website, i just want that post to appear t all logged in user. Does that clear it for you @GrumpyCrouton